# Display category products on homepage using carousel slider

Tags: product, magento-1.9, category, custom, home

I am able to display products from specific categories on homepage using duplicate copies of list.phtml and with the help of this code.

It just displaying flat 4 products but I want to display more products using slider and `column_count = 4`

> {{block type="catalog/product_list" column_count="4" category_id="3" template="catalog/product/list-officestationery.phtml"}}

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me how you create that phtml ?

Answer (score 2):

Block shortcode should have an option to specify products count.
Usually it is **product_count**

Try to update code to

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" column_count="4" category_id="3" product_count="12" template="catalog/product/list-officestationery.phtml"}}
```

Please note that chosen category should contain enough products.