# Carousel on CMS page from different categories

Tags: magento-enterprise, product-list, slider

I would like to have product carousels on my homepage using 3-4 different product categories.

That means i would have my left and right sidebar and then in the middle I would like to have the following

Carousel 1 (3 products Category 1)

Carousel 2 (3 products Category 2)

Carousel 3 (....

and so on [similar to this one](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/38400/display-category-products-on-homepage-using-carousel)

Is that somehow possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done mostly in the CMS.

For the carousel you need some kind of JavaScript library, like [OWL Carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/), if your theme doesn't already come with a slider widget.

See [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58252/add-owl-carousel-to-homepage-in-magento-ce-1-9) about how to integrate it.

Then, you can use widgets to insert product images/links inside the single elements of the carousel.

Comment: how do i fill these carousels then from different categories?

Comment: This approach needs manual selection of each product.

Comment: It seems like you have a deep understanding of it. Do you know if there is a code snippet online or tutorial how its done?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any.

Comment: I will try my best and see if i can get it to work smoothly and then update the question thanks !

Comment: I ended up using TinyCarousel but it works probably the same way http://baijs.com/tinycarousel/